# In Lucene, using a Standard Analyzer, I want to make fields with spaces and special characters searchable

Tags: lucene

In Lucene, using a Standard Analyzer, I want to make fields with spaces and special characters(underscore,!,@,#,....) searchable.

I set IndexField to NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS and Field.Store.YES

When I look at my index in LUKE, the fields are as I expected, a value such as:

'SKU Number', yet when I search for 'SKU' or 'SKU*' nothing comes up.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching for 'SKU' won't work because you indexed with NOT_ANALYZED;  'SKU Number' is the entire indexed term.  If you want words split by whitespace, that's what ANALYZED is for.

Now doing a prefix search, 'SKU*', would work except by default the lucene QueryParser lowercases expanded terms.  Set [lowercaseExpandedTerms](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/QueryParser.html#setLowercaseExpandedTerms(boolean)) on the parser to False.

Answer (score 0):

Field.Store.YES does not influence the search behaviour on this field. And I'd set IndexField to simply NOT_ANALYZED.

Try to perform search in Luke on full field text 'SKU Number' using KeywordAnalyzer analyzer.