# In Lucene, using a Standard Analyzer, I want to make fields with spaces searchable

Tags: lucene

In Lucene, using a Standard Analyzer, I want to make fields with space searchable.
I set Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED and Field.Store.YES using the StandardAnalyzer
When I look at my index in LUKE, the fields are as I expected, a field and a value such as:
location -> 'New York'.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540818/in-lucene-using-a-standard-analyzer-i-want-to-make-fields-with-spaces-and-speci/2540989#2540989) I found that I can use the KeywordAnalyzer to find this value using the query:
location:"New York".

But I want to add another term to the query. Let's say a have a body field which contains the normalized and analyzed terms created by the StandardAnalyzer. Using the KeywordAnalyzer for this field I get different results than when I use the StandardAnalyzer.

How do I combine two Analyzers in one QueryParser, where one Analyzer works for some fields and another one for another fields. I though of creating my own Analyzer which could behave differently depending on the field, but I have no clue how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper.html) lets you apply different analyzers for different fields.

Comment: This was the solution we used for the exact same problem.  I recommend creating a public getAnalyzer method that can be used by both the Searcher and the Writer.